# How to use Gcovr Installed with pip on windows

Tags: python, pip, gcov, gcovr

So I followed this [guide](http://gcovr.com/guide.html#installation) and managed to install Gcovr using pip (I already have Python installed along with Anaconda). I tried to use `gcovr` but this is what I got:

[image: gcovr result]

When I use `pip list`, Gcovr is already installed.
[image: pip list result]

How do I use it?

I'm running Windows 7 64bit with Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 64bit

P.S:
I'm sorry if this has already been asked before but after searching around for days I've yet to found any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gcovr 3.x is a bit more cumbersome on Windows because Windows doesn't seem to recognize the gcovr script as an executable. Instead: find out where gcovr was installed to (e.g. by running pip in `--verbose` mode), then explicitly invoke Python:

```
> python C:\path\to\gcovr
```

The path is probably something like `C:\Python35\Scripts`.

You can also write a batch file to wrap gcovr like this.

Please also consider updating (`pip install -U gcovr`), as gcovr 3.4 fixes some other bugs on Windows.

This installation issue will be fixed in the next release. If you want to, you can already install the development version directly from GitHub:

```
> pip install git+https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr.git
```